# How to update the properties of CMFCPropertyGridCtrl?

Tags: c++, mfc

I'm developing an application that binds a data model and a user interface together through MFC and I'm trying to use the CMFCPropertyGridCtrl to display and edit the data that's extracted from the data model.Then after I finish editing the properities shown on the CMFCPropertyGridCtrl, I need to move the new updated data back to the data model. When doing this, I need to check if the data in the CMFCPropertyGridCtrl is really updated before the data transfer is executed. I achieve it through checking the return value of IsModified method. But after I move data back to data model, the CMFCPropertyGridCtrl doesn't update its properties itself. So the IsModified method will never work since it just compares the current value to the initial value, not the updated value. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: AFAIK IsModified is a flag, and this flag is set depending on the type of property. I see no comparision in the base code. I see just a flag that is set and returned by IsModified.

Comment: Well, sorry for my wrong description. I didn't verify the comparision from the base code, I just infer it from the behavior that the IsModified method will return true as long as its current value is not equal to its initial value. Actually I didn't find how the IsModified flag is set and since it's a protected member of  CMFCPropertyGridCtrl, I can't change it directly.

Comment: m_bModified is cleared by the function CMFCPropertyGridProperty::ResetOriginalValue! In this case m_varValueOrig is set back to the property. The original value may changed by SetOriginalValue.

Comment: I just try it as you said. It works, thank you so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CMFCPropertyGridCtrl::OnPropertyChanged is designed to track a change in a property and to reflect the Change to your system. This virtual function is called by CMFCPropertyGridProperty::OnUpdateValue.

Because m_bModified is discussed here to here some words about it, because it causes sometimes confusion:
m_bModified is cleared by the function CMFCPropertyGridProperty::ResetOriginalValue! In this case m_varValueOrig is set back to the property. The original value may changed by SetOriginalValue.

So the only good position to check and track changes is CMFCPropertyGridCtrl::OnPropertyChanged. If a property is changed, IsModified is true. But this only compared to the original value...

Comment: Well, I just want to find a way to make CMFCPropertyGridCtrl update its inner data after every time of data transfer so that I can check if they are modified referring to the new updated data, not the original one. I don't quite understand your answer.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see your last comment before I reply to your answer. I thought it could very likely works, I will sort it out later.

Answer (score 0):

If you're updating value and want to see your modifications in bold text, then it makes sense to use `CMFCPropertyGridProperty::SetValue` and `CMFCPropertyGridProperty::SetOriginalValue` in initialization phase.

But next time you want to get your value to be updated use `CMFCPropertyGridProperty::SetValue` and then call manually to `CMFCPropertyGridCtrl::OnPropertyChanged( pointer to your property )`

That function will call `protected SetModifiedFlag()` function, which in a turn will update `protected m_bIsModified` to have correct value.